# dask distributed results in TypeError

Tags: python-2.7, dask-distributed

I just tried pip install distributed. dask-scheduler is running but result returns as error. Is this an installation issue? Would any package be missing?
Or is this a conflict of versions issue?

```
>>> from distributed import Client
>>> c=Client()
>>> def sq(x):
...     return x+1
...
>>> c.submit(sq,2)
>>> x=c.submit(sq,2)
>>> x
<Future: status: finished, type: int, key: sq-dcc8bc750c0ce57c2d052675a6cd33b9>

>>> x.result()

distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to deserialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 119, in loads
    value = _deserialize(head, fs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 158, in deserialize
    return f(header, frames)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    deserializers = {None: lambda header, frames: 

...

packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 20, in <lambda>
        deserializers = {None: lambda header, frames: pickle.loads(b''.join(frames))}
    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, bytearray found
    >>>
```

Comment: It's a bug for Python 2, you can lookup for this particular issue at https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1816